# Kafka golang producer changing partition count after error

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka producer that lost communication to the broker temporarily. Each topic is defined with 10 partitions. When a connection is lost, I see the following log in the process running the producer:

```
%3|1690891270.524|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:my_ip:9092/bootstrap]: my_ip:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#my_ip:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 10 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1690891273.524|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:my_ip:9093/bootstrap]: my_ip:9093/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#my_ip:9093 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 7 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1690891273.584|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:hostname:9094/1001]: hostname:9094/1001: Connect to ipv4#my_ip:9094 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 4 identical error(s) suppressed)
%4|1690891277.639|CLUSTERID|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Broker my_ip:9092/bootstrap reports different ClusterId "TkRgxModQH-mlCkT9mr3lQ" than previously known "o4j9GSQrQ5Svuwvq4uiWQQ": a client must not be simultaneously connected to multiple clusters
%5|1690891278.529|PARTCNT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Topic my_topic partition count changed from 10 to 1
```

my producer configuration is as basic as it gets:

```
    config := kafka.ConfigMap{
        "security.protocol": "plaintext",
        "bootstrap.servers": my_ip,
    }

    producer, err := kafka.NewProducer(&config)
```

My docker compose with kafka:

```
zoo1:
    image: "${IMAGE_ZOOKEEPER}"
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888;zoo2:2888:3888;zoo3:2888:3888
    networks:
      - internal_network

  zoo2:
    image: "${IMAGE_ZOOKEEPER}"
    hostname: zoo2
    container_name: zoo2
    ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:2182:2182"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2182
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888;zoo2:2888:3888;zoo3:2888:3888
    networks:
      - internal_network

  zoo3:
    image: "${IMAGE_ZOOKEEPER}"
    hostname: zoo3
    container_name: zoo3
    ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:2183:2183"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2183
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888;zoo2:2888:3888;zoo3:2888:3888
    networks:
      - internal_network

  kafka1:
    image: "${IMAGE_KAFKA}"
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:29092,EXTERNAL://niro:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181,zoo2:2182,zoo3:2183"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    networks:
      - internal_network

  kafka2:
    image: "${IMAGE_KAFKA}"
    hostname: kafka2
    container_name: kafka2
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
      - "29093:29093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:29093,EXTERNAL://niro:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181,zoo2:2182,zoo3:2183"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    networks:
      - internal_network

  kafka3:
    image: "${IMAGE_KAFKA}"
    hostname: kafka3
    container_name: kafka3
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
      - "29094:29094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29094,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka3:29094,EXTERNAL://niro:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181,zoo2:2182,zoo3:2183"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    networks:
      - internal_network

  kafka-topic-create:
    image: "${IMAGE_KAFKA}"
    hostname: kafka-topic-create
    container_name: kafka-topic-create
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
    entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
    command: |
      "
      # blocks until kafka is reachable
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka1:29092 --list

      echo -e 'Creating kafka topics'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka1:29092 --create --if-not-exists --topic my_topic --replication-factor 1 --partitions 10

      echo -e 'Successfully created the following topics for Kafka1:'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka1:29092 --list

      echo -e 'Kafka2:'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka2:29093 --list
      echo -e 'Kafka3:'

      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka3:29094 --list


      "

    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: ignored
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: ignored
    networks:
      - internal_network
```

Where the images are `confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2`, `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2`

Why is kafka changing the partitions on its own? How do I prevent this?
thank you

Comment: It's not changing partitions... Are you running multiple brokers, or not? Your logs suggest you've provided 3 brokers to the bootstrap servers, but they're not part of a cluster. Show your cluster setup. Also, running 3 brokers all on localhost is not recommended

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm running 3 brokers in a docker compose, with 3 zookeepers as well. some topics remain with 10 partitions but some that appear in the logs change. I'll edit my answer to show the kafka topic creation and my docker compose. If the partitions aren't changing, what is happening?

Comment: Again, not partitions. It's cycling through the list of **brokers**, and not connecting. Then finds one with a different `clusterId` since you have no volumes stored, therefore there is no persistence, and the ID will be different if the containers ever restart... Also, not clear why you are trying to list the topics 3 times from the same cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set env-var on each broker

```
KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
```

This should solve your `my_topic partition count changed from 10 to 1`.

The reason it changes to one is that your broker is apparently restarting, and that is the default for auto-created topics (your previous topic had been deleted)

If you want to find out why the topic had been deleted, or why Kafka is not connecting / restarting, you need to debug the broker logs, not your Golang app.

You also don't need three brokers here. Especially considering that your topic has 1 replica... One broker can also host topics with 10 partitions.

---

Maybe your brokers are failing because your machine is running out of memory, for example. Docker for Windows/Mac defaults to start with only 2G of RAM, I think, but each broker starts with at least 1G heap space needed, and then there's also Zookeeper